# css footer position only working half the time

Tags: html, css

I have a simple page where a user can make a search, and results populate the page. Before the search is made, there is a simple form, some white space, and the footer with social media links.

If i use a fixed position on the footer, I get the desired effect before a search is made, but after, the footer sits atop the final results.

I can fix this using an inherit position, but then the footer doesn't sit at the bottom on the page before the search.

I've tried using the fixe dposition and adding bottom padding to the body equal to the height of the footer, but that doesn't do anything in this case.

Any ideas?

Here is a link to the current build on heroku, where you can see the problem in action. It is using a fixed position on the footer. Also this is a React project for fyi.

https://grub-finder.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I'd probably add a class to `body` when a user makes a search via JS and use that to change the footer to `position: static;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to do this easily. You want to set your react root div to be at least the height of the viewport, then set your results element to `flex-grow: 1` so that it consumes all of the left over space, and it will push the footer to the bottom of the window.

Add this CSS

```
[data-reactroot] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.DisplayRecs {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Remove `width`, `position`, and `bottom` from `.Footer`